# Can't find code that renders a page in Django

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner trying to customize an open source Django app. In urls.py, I see this pattern:

```
url(r'^asset/list/$', generic_list, dict({'queryset':Item.objects.all()}, list_filters=[location_filter, state_filter], extra_context=dict(title=_(u'assets'))), 'item_list'),
```

I expected to find a view called 'item_list' but there is no such view. How is this page being rendered? Is there some background magic going on?

(Loading this URL throws an error - `"'function' object has no attribute 'status_code'"`, which I am trying to debug)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the basic url function is :

```
url(<regularexpression>,<view.py function>,<optional_dictionary>,<optional_name>)
```

so in your `url()`:

- the Python callback function(ie view.py function) is `generic_list`
- and the aguments passed to it are

  - `{'queryset':Item.objects.all()}`
  - `list_filters=[location_filter, state_filter]`
  - `extra_context=dict(title=_(u'assets'))`
- and the name of url is :`item_list`
  (which will be useful when creating urls. for eg: `{% url 'item_list' %}`)

so in your case the python function  is `generic_list` not `item_list`